# wait for callback function to be completed before proceeding to next line javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, asynccallback

I am trying to optimize an existing `javascript` code and finding it hard with `callback` methods. This is `pure javascript` and `no jQuery, Ajax call, or other frameworks involved`.

Here is the issue

```
function A() {
  // getSomeData is a method which takes parameter and a callback
  getSomeData(params, function(details) { 
    // a lot of code in this callback
  });
}
```

The `getSomeData` is being used in many places and passing a `different callback` at each usage. Trying to optimize and want to use a common method as below but unable to. I like the `async/await` approach if possible, else `Promise`

```
functionB(keys) {
    getSomeData(keys, function(details) {
        // move some common code to callback and update some global vars
    });
}

functionA() {
  // some code block-a
  functionB(keys);
  console.log(global.x); // this global.x is populated in callback of getSomeData
  // some code block-b
}
```

How ever in the above code, when the `functionB` is called and without waiting for `callback` to be completed, the `console.log(global.x)` is printed as `empty/null/undefined` since `javascript is async`.

How to achieve this to be `synchronous`

I tried defining `functionB` to be `async` as below but did not work

```
async functionB(keys) {
    await getSomeData(keys, function(details) {
        // move some common code to callback and update some global vars
    });
}
```

PS: `getSomeData(params, callback)` cannot be modified as it is out of control